# In side SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), can we use access token for unit test?

Tags: azure, access-token, sql-server-data-tools

In side **SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)**, can we use access token for **unit test** of database?

Comment: you can pass  it as variable

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, Can you please tell me how?

Comment: use `'$(AccessToken)'` in the code where it is needed and then define it's value in the publish profile. Make sure you haven't omitted single quotes as you need to be it as the string in the code